# regex to validate phone number jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I would like to add a mobile validation along with existing validation to my mobile number field.

The validation I want is

- the numbers 8 and 9 must not be repeated consecutively 10 times in the mobile number.Eg: `8888888888`

The existing validation includes the digits 7,8, OR 9 as the starting number and remaining any numbers between (0-9).

My existing regex code : `/^[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/`.

Please help me out to find a solution.

Comment: You could think over using [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) which will handle various formats of different countries and type of numbers.

Comment: I just need to avoid the digits 8 and 9 from consecutively repeating 10 times.So what must be the changes I need to make with my existing validation

Comment: But `9888888888` and `8999999999` would be valid?

Comment: Yes 9888888888 and 8999999999 are valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this solution using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

`^(?![8]{10}|[9]{10})[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the jquery validate plugin

http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/

and add you own rules for validation depending on the originating country

http://cooshtee.com/blog/2012/06/jquery-validation-for-a-uk-phone-number-and-uk-postcode/

Comment: Thanks.. But I just need to avoid the digits 8 and 9 from consecutively repeating 10 times.So what must be the changes I need to make with my existing validation